# TKinter: lost alignment between frame and root

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, alignment

I am running into a curious problem. I have a small grid (8 rows, 5 columns). Root with a couple of frames. Most run fine. Four fields of the the top row (1 in my case, I do not use 0) have a text and must have the same color continuously. I could not realise this in root itself so I made a frame (text=""), with labels. That gives the desired look apart from the fact that all the texts are concatenated at the left and no longer above the gridfields below. 
The code is realy very simple but I expect it will be requested anyway so here is the relevant part:

```
# Top frame
top_frame=LabelFrame(root, text= "", bg=top_line_color)
top_frame.grid(row =1, column=0, sticky=W+E, columnspan=5)

# Fixed labels:
Label(top_frame, text="Anten", font=fnt, bg=top_line_color).grid(row=1, 
column=0)
Label(top_frame, text="Antenna", font=fnt, bg=top_line_color).grid(row=1, 
column=1)
Label(top_frame, text="Corr.", font=fnt, width=4, 
bg=top_line_color).grid(row=1, column=3)
Label(top_frame, text="Move", font=fnt, width=4, 
bg=top_line_color).grid(row=1, sticky=W, column=4)
Label(root, text="Azimuth:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Elevation:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=3, 
sticky=W) 
Label(root, text="Location:",justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text=acemedat.myloc, font=fnt).grid(row=4, column=1)
Label(root, text="Dat/Tim:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=4, column=2) 
Label(root, text="Moon distance (km):", font=fnt).grid(row=5, columnspan=2, 
sticky=W)
```

The labels are followed by data fields (in root as well). They comply with the grid without problem. 
What can I do to to align the frame fields with the root fields?
Many thanks in advance,
Harke

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to line up in a grid, the easiest solution is to put them all in the same frame. If you use the `sticky` attribute for the fixed labels, you can have a solid, unbroken color. Depending on your system, you might need to change the labels to have a `borderwidth` and/or `highlightthickness` of zero. If you want the labels to be left-aligned, you can do that with the `anchor` attribute of the labels.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

fnt = ("Helvetica", "12")
top_line_color = "bisque"

# Fixed labels:
Label(root, text="Anten", font=fnt, bg=top_line_color,
      anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
Label(root, text="Antenna", font=fnt, bg=top_line_color,
      anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
Label(root, text="Corr.", font=fnt, width=4, bg=top_line_color,
      anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
Label(root, text="Move", font=fnt, width=4, bg=top_line_color,
      anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nsew")

Label(root, text="Azimuth:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Elevation:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=3,  sticky=W) 
Label(root, text="Location:",justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="acemedat.myloc", font=fnt).grid(row=4, column=1)
Label(root, text="Dat/Tim:", justify=RIGHT, font=fnt).grid(row=4, column=2) 
Label(root, text="Moon distance (km):", font=fnt).grid(row=5, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I have some food for thought and experimentation. Thanks again!